# HMAC-SHA1 implementation

Tags: c, reinventing-the-wheel, cryptography, openssl

I am trying out a small piece of code that would generate HMAC-SHA1. I have been asked to code the HMAC implementation myself using the OpenSSL libs for SHA1 calculation.

After 'wiki'ing for the algorithm, here is what I have below.  I have used input with RFC 2104 specified test values:

> key =         0x0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b
>   key_len =     16
>       bytes
>   data =        "Hi There"
>   data_len =    8  bytes    digest =
>       0x9294727a3638bb1c13f48ef8158bfc9d

But the output I get is:

```
675b0b3a1b4ddf4e124872da6c2f632bfed957e9*
```

Is this really not the way to implement HMAC? How else can this be done?

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/conf.h>
#include <openssl/engine.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>     /* for memset() */
#include <unistd.h>

#define IPAD 0x36
#define OPAD 0x5C

#define SHA1_DIGESTLENGTH 20
#define SHA1_BLOCK_LENGTH 64
#define COUNTER_LENGTH 8

typedef unsigned          char uint8_t;
typedef unsigned short     int uint16_t;
typedef unsigned           int uint32_t;

/**
 * Key
 */
#define SECRET { 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b , 0x0b}
#define COUNTER {  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }
/*
 * hmac sha1.
 */
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    unsigned char ipad[SHA1_BLOCK_LENGTH];
    unsigned char opad[SHA1_BLOCK_LENGTH];
    unsigned char algKey[SHA1_BLOCK_LENGTH];
    unsigned char msgBuffer[SHA1_BLOCK_LENGTH + COUNTER_LENGTH];
    unsigned char valBuffer[SHA1_BLOCK_LENGTH + 20];
    unsigned int i;
    uint8_t ctr[] = "Hi There";
    uint8_t hash[20];
    uint8_t key[]= SECRET;
    int len = 16;
    memset(hash, 0, sizeof(hash));
    memset(algKey, 0, sizeof(algKey));
    strncpy((char *)algKey, (char *)key, len);

    memset(ipad, IPAD, sizeof(ipad));
    memset(opad, OPAD, sizeof(opad));

    for (i = 0; i < SHA1_BLOCK_LENGTH; i++){
        ipad[i] ^= algKey[i];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < SHA1_BLOCK_LENGTH; i++){
        opad[i] ^= algKey[i];
    }

    memset(msgBuffer, 0, sizeof(msgBuffer));

    strncpy((char *)msgBuffer, (char *)ipad, SHA1_BLOCK_LENGTH);
    strncpy((char *)msgBuffer + SHA1_BLOCK_LENGTH, (char *)ctr, COUNTER_LENGTH);


    EVP_MD_CTX mdctx, md_ctx;
    const EVP_MD *md;

    unsigned char md_value[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
    unsigned int md_len;

    OpenSSL_add_all_digests();


    md = EVP_get_digestbyname("sha1");

    if(!md) {
        printf("Unknown message digest\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    EVP_MD_CTX_init(&mdctx);
    EVP_DigestInit_ex(&mdctx, md, NULL);
    EVP_DigestUpdate(&mdctx, msgBuffer,(SHA1_BLOCK_LENGTH + COUNTER_LENGTH) );
    EVP_DigestFinal_ex(&mdctx, md_value, &md_len);
    EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(&mdctx);


    printf("Digest is: ");
    for(i = 0; i < md_len; i++) printf("%02x", md_value[i]);
    printf("\n");

    unsigned char *copy;
    copy = malloc(md_len);
    strncpy((char*)copy, (char *)md_value, md_len);


    memset(valBuffer, 0, sizeof(valBuffer));
    strncpy((char *)valBuffer, (char *)opad, SHA1_BLOCK_LENGTH);
    strncpy((char *)valBuffer + SHA1_BLOCK_LENGTH, (char *)copy, md_len);

    EVP_MD_CTX_init(&md_ctx);
    EVP_DigestInit_ex(&md_ctx, md, NULL);
    EVP_DigestUpdate(&md_ctx, valBuffer, SHA1_BLOCK_LENGTH + 20);
    printf( "updated Digest..\n");
    EVP_DigestFinal_ex(&md_ctx, md_value, &md_len);
    EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(&md_ctx);

    printf("Digest is: ");
    for(i = 0; i < md_len; i++) printf("%02x", md_value[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

- You can make these `#define`s:

  ```
  #define SHA1_DIGESTLENGTH 20
  #define SHA1_BLOCK_LENGTH 64
  #define COUNTER_LENGTH 8
  ```

  into a more concise `enum`:

  ```
  typedef enum { COUNTER=8, SHA1_DIGEST=20, SHA1_BLOCK=64 } Length;
  ```

  This could also be done with `SECRET` and `COUNTER`, but each hex value would need a name.

  If you use the `enum` recommendation, you may need to rename the second `COUNTER` to avoid possible name-clashing.  Perhaps rename it based on what the counter is for.
- You don't need your own `typedef`s for these:

  ```
  typedef unsigned           char uint8_t;
  typedef unsigned short     int uint16_t;
  typedef unsigned           int uint32_t;
  ```

  Prefer to use the `typedef`s already defined in [`<stdint.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer).
- For unformatted output with a newline, use `puts()` instead of `printf()`:

  ```
  puts("Some text...");
  ```
- I'd recommend splitting this program into separate functions.  This will make it easier to tell how the it works and make it easier to maintain.  A function should have one purpose, and`main()` should have minimal implementation (such as acquiring input and calling other functions).
- There's no need to call `exit(1)` within `main()`.  Just `return 1`.

  The `return 0` is also not needed at the end.  Reaching this point implies successful termination, so the compiler will do this return for you.

Answer (score 2):

Might I suggest using OpenSSL's built in [`HMAC_*`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/HMAC.html) methods, instead of re-rolling?